# removing specific element from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some svg elements that are used to make up a map of the world. They look like this:

```
<path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="Afghanistan"
     onmouseover="displayName(this)"
     data-name="Afghanistan"
     data-id="AF"
     d="m 1369.9,333.8 -5.4,0 -3.8,-0.5 -2.5,2.9 -2.1,0.7 -1.5,1.3 -2.6,-2.1 -1,-5.4 -1.6,-0.3 0,-2 -3.2,-1.5 -1.7,2.3 0.2,2.6 -0.6,0.9 -3.2,-0.1 -0.9,3 -2.1,-1.3 -3.3,2.1 -1.8,-0.8 -4.3,-1.4 -2.9,0 -1.6,-0.2 -2.9,-1.7 -0.3,2.3 -4.1,1.2 0.1,5.2 -2.5,2 -4,0.9 -0.4,3 -3.9,0.8 -5.9,-2.4 -0.5,8 -0.5,4.7 2.5,0.9 -1.6,3.5 2.7,5.1 1.1,4 4.3,1.1 1.1,4 -3.9,5.8 9.6,3.2 5.3,-0.9 3.3,0.8 0.9,-1.4 3.8,0.5 6.6,-2.6 -0.8,-5.4 2.3,-3.6 4,0 0.2,-1.7 4,-0.9 2.1,0.6 1.7,-1.8 -1.1,-3.8 1.5,-3.8 3,-1.6 -3,-4.2 5.1,0.2 0.9,-2.3 -0.8,-2.5 2,-2.7 -1.4,-3.2 -1.9,-2.8 2.4,-2.8 5.3,-1.3 5.8,-0.8 2.4,-1.2 2.8,-0.7 -1.4,-1.9 z"></path>
```

I want to be able to click on one of these elements which is generated at random.If the user correctly clicks the randomly generated country it will change color to white, if they take two attempts it will be orange, three or more attempts it highlights the correct country for the user to click. Once the user clicks the correct country a new randomly generated country will be produced.

Thanks to Alex L, I have all of the countries in a variable and functions that will change the color and randomly generate a country each time the start button is clicked.

```
const allPaths = document.querySelectorAll('svg > path');

function displayName(elem){
   console.log(elem.id)
}

allPaths.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', myFuncHandler));

function myFuncHandler(e){
   const country_id = e.target.id;
   const thisCountry = e.target.getAttribute('data-name');
   const colour = thisCountry == targetSpan.innerHTML ? "#ffffff" : "#8a0000";
   e.target.style.fill = colour;

}

const StartButton = document.querySelector('#startButton');
StartButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
   const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (allPaths.length));
   const randCountry = allPaths[randIndex];
   targetSpan.innerHTML = randCountry.getAttribute('data-name');
   allPaths.forEach(elem => elem.style.fill = '#008000');
});
```

To achieve what I want, I believe I need to use the splice array method in some way. The color change is nearly there, I think I can just user the ? syntax a bit more as is done in the myFuncHandler function.

Comment: It's much better if you can provide a working example of your problem for us to effectively help. To be honest, I have no idea what you're talking about nor what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @masterpreenz edited to make things clearer (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is building off my last answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431954/9792594

So I build on this for your requirements here.

Better to look at the demo in codePen (as there is a char limit here so I can't include all countries): https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/ExVXEOq

Note: each time they get it correct, we splice it out the array. This means up front you need to put the nodelist into an array with `const allPaths = [...document.querySelectorAll("svg path")];`

```js
const targetSpan = document.querySelector("#target");
const allPaths = [...document.querySelectorAll("svg path")];
const attempts = document.querySelector("#attempts");
/*
function displayName(elem){
  console.log(elem.id)
}
*/
allPaths.forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", myFuncHandler));

function myFuncHandler(e) {
  const country_id = e.target.id;
  const thisCountry = e.target.getAttribute("title");
  if (thisCountry == targetSpan.innerHTML) {
    const colour = "#004400"; //green
    e.target.style.fill = colour;
    const correctInd = allPaths.findIndex(
      (el) => el.getAttribute("title") == targetSpan.innerHTML
    );
    allPaths.splice(correctInd, 1);
    nextCountry(e);
  } else {
    const currAttempt = parseInt(attempts.innerHTML);
    if (currAttempt >= 3) {
      //find correct answer
      const correctAns = allPaths.find(
        (el) => el.getAttribute("title") == targetSpan.innerHTML
      );
      const colour = "#63d463"; //light-green
      correctAns.style.fill = colour;
    } else {
      attempts.innerHTML = currAttempt + 1;
      const colour = "#d4800b"; //orange
      e.target.style.fill = colour;
    }
  }
}

const startButton = document.querySelector("#startButton");
startButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  startButton.disabled = true;
  nextCountry(e);
});

function nextCountry(e) {
  attempts.innerHTML = 1;
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * allPaths.length);
  const randCountry = allPaths[randIndex];
  targetSpan.innerHTML = randCountry.getAttribute("title");
  allPaths.forEach((elem) => (elem.style.fill = "#CCCCCC"));
}
```

```html
<button id="startButton">Start Game</button>
<h4>Please click on <span id="target">___</span>; attempt <span id="attempts">1</span> of 3</h4>

<svg id="world" width="800px" height="500px" viewport="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      .land {
        fill: #CCCCCC;
        fill-opacity: 1;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-opacity: 1;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
      }
    </style>

    <amcharts:ammap projection="mercator" leftLongitude="-169.6" topLatitude="83.68" rightLongitude="190.25" bottomLatitude="-55.55" />

  </defs>
  <g style="transform: scale(0.7)">
    <path id="AF" title="Afghanistan" class="land" d="M646.879,356.901L649.738,358.201L651.853,357.745L652.438,356.188L654.651,355.669L656.231,354.617L656.791,351.832L659.154,351.154L659.594,349.902L660.917,350.843L661.762,350.952L663.323,350.975L665.438,351.716L666.295,352.143L668.324,351.017L669.27,351.694L670.174,350.085L671.85,350.159L672.281,349.641L672.578,348.213L673.785,346.975L675.303,347.785L674.998,348.869L675.846,349.038L675.585,351.994L676.694,353.137L677.672,352.404L678.916,352.057L680.663,350.486L682.594,350.745L685.486,350.751L685.985,351.758L684.353,352.15L682.928,352.795L679.71,353.2L676.699,353.931L675.063,355.439L675.725,356.899L676.046,358.603L674.649,360.033L674.766,361.335L673.995,362.549L671.328,362.444L672.43,364.663L670.646,365.507L669.455,367.511L669.609,369.491L668.514,370.415L667.477,370.109L665.334,370.537L665.027,371.451L662.939,371.446L661.377,373.289L661.278,376.039L657.635,377.374L655.682,377.092L655.114,377.794L653.438,377.386L650.634,377.865L645.936,376.228L648.479,373.298L648.249,371.202L646.125,370.65L645.905,368.565L644.987,365.921L646.187,364.094L644.966,363.599L645.736,361.148z" />
    <path id="AR" title="Argentina" class="land" d="M291.601,648.907l-2.664,0.245l-1.43,-1.726l-1.689,-0.13l-3.002,-0.003l-0.002,-10.568l1.077,2.148l1.402,3.525l3.645,2.865l3.925,1.207L291.601,648.907zM293.101,526.469l1.648,2.178l1.094,-2.426l3.197,0.125l0.453,0.644l5.155,4.945l2.292,0.464l3.426,2.262l2.888,1.202l0.402,1.362l-2.76,4.731l2.827,0.854l3.149,0.479l2.217,-0.505l2.543,-2.398l0.458,-2.743l1.389,-0.593l1.407,1.789l-0.057,2.489l-2.361,1.729l-1.883,1.282l-3.165,3.078l-3.741,4.372l-0.701,2.594l-0.75,3.365l0.028,3.297l-0.608,0.742l-0.217,2.165l-0.192,1.761l3.56,2.914l-0.383,2.368l1.752,1.507l-0.143,1.7l-2.694,4.516l-4.157,1.913l-5.624,0.746l-3.08,-0.361l0.589,2.147l-0.574,2.721l0.518,1.851l-1.682,1.299l-2.874,0.512l-2.696,-1.347l-1.083,0.967l0.391,3.71l1.893,1.135l1.535,-1.189l0.835,1.962l-2.582,1.18l-2.251,2.383l-0.412,3.907l-0.663,2.107l-2.648,0.011l-2.198,2.035l-0.804,3.013l2.757,2.982l2.681,0.831l-0.964,3.726l-3.312,2.375l-1.822,5.025l-2.559,1.719l-1.149,2.059l0.905,4.641l1.866,2.633l-1.182,-0.231l-2.599,-0.715l-6.775,-0.608l-1.162,-2.632l0.054,-3.332l-1.867,0.284l-0.988,-1.596l-0.245,-4.599l2.151,-1.878l0.889,-2.68l-0.326,-2.112l1.486,-3.52l1.024,-5.35l-0.301,-2.331l1.224,-0.748l-0.3,-1.478l-1.301,-0.782l0.924,-1.63l-1.266,-1.462l-0.655,-4.395l1.127,-0.767l-0.474,-4.543l0.659,-3.751l0.75,-3.223l1.679,-1.3l-0.853,-3.462l-0.009,-3.217l2.123,-2.263l-0.065,-2.868l1.6,-3.313l0.007,-3.086l-0.728,-0.609l-1.292,-5.694l1.728,-3.343l-0.265,-3.115l1.002,-2.896l1.836,-2.963l1.979,-1.95l-0.839,-1.225l0.585,-1.001l-0.089,-5.143l3.054,-1.509l0.962,-3.159l-0.34,-0.758l2.336,-2.722L293.101,526.469z" />
    <path id="AU" title="Australia" class="land" d="M882.928,588.16l2.709,1.277l1.526,-0.508l2.188,-0.71l1.682,0.248l0.199,4.425l-0.961,1.3l-0.289,3.064l-0.98,-1.047l-1.946,2.675l-0.58,-0.208l-1.725,-0.12l-1.729,-3.276l-0.384,-2.496l-1.617,-3.254l0.071,-1.695L882.928,588.16zM877.779,502.097l1.01,2.254l1.799,-1.084l0.929,1.218l1.346,1.125l-0.288,1.28l0.598,2.484l0.426,1.452l0.706,0.355l0.761,2.495l-0.271,1.52l0.908,1.995l3.038,1.542l1.98,1.407l1.881,1.292l-0.367,0.721l1.604,1.872l1.09,3.249l1.119,-0.662l1.137,1.306l0.686,-0.464l0.483,3.208l1.989,1.871l1.302,1.167l2.191,2.488l0.788,2.487l0.072,1.774l-0.193,1.937l1.336,2.676l-0.16,2.811l-0.485,1.48l-0.757,2.871l0.057,1.859l-0.555,2.34l-1.238,2.996l-2.077,1.631l-1.023,2.59l-0.936,1.666l-0.831,2.932l-1.082,1.707l-0.709,2.583l-0.362,2.401l0.144,1.109l-1.607,1.224l-3.139,0.128l-2.588,1.454l-1.288,1.38l-1.694,1.539l-2.322,-1.584l-1.718,-0.629l0.436,-1.851l-1.533,0.67l-2.455,2.582l-2.424,-0.97l-1.59,-0.564l-1.604,-0.254l-2.714,-1.027l-1.813,-2.175l-0.521,-2.655l-0.651,-1.752l-1.378,-1.398l-2.697,-0.414l0.922,-1.661l-0.679,-2.522l-1.369,2.351l-2.495,0.627l1.467,-1.885l0.425,-1.953l1.083,-1.646l-0.225,-2.472l-2.28,2.849l-1.752,1.15l-1.074,2.693l-2.189,-1.396l0.087,-1.791l-1.754,-2.43l-1.479,-1.247l0.527,-0.766l-3.598,-2.001l-1.971,-0.094l-2.696,-1.597l-5.021,0.31l-3.631,1.175l-3.19,1.1l-2.676,-0.219l-2.972,1.696l-2.432,0.766l-0.54,1.75l-1.035,1.363l-2.38,0.082l-1.761,0.299l-2.478,-0.613l-2.017,0.367l-1.925,0.154l-1.668,1.801l-0.817,-0.153l-1.406,0.959l-1.348,1.082l-2.046,-0.134l-1.879,-0.001l-2.975,-2.168l-1.507,-0.642l0.061,-1.927l1.393,-0.456l0.476,-0.761l-0.1,-1.196l0.343,-2.302l-0.313,-1.948l-1.482,-3.294l-0.46,-1.845l0.121,-1.83l-1.116,-2.079l-0.071,-0.934l-1.242,-1.262l-0.35,-2.468l-1.603,-2.477l-0.388,-1.327l1.231,1.346l-0.946,-2.881l1.391,0.898l0.83,1.203l-0.047,-1.59l-1.388,-2.43l-0.269,-0.968l-0.65,-0.917l0.305,-1.767l0.574,-0.75l0.383,-1.519l-0.3,-1.768l1.159,-2.165l0.211,2.292l1.185,-2.071l2.278,-1.002l1.366,-1.276l2.143,-1.095l1.274,-0.232l0.772,0.367l2.209,-1.109l1.701,-0.33l0.425,-0.65l0.742,-0.271l1.55,0.07l2.947,-0.867l1.524,-1.313l0.716,-1.575l1.645,-1.491l0.126,-1.169l0.073,-1.589l1.962,-2.474l1.181,2.514l1.193,-0.582l-0.998,-1.375l0.88,-1.409l1.237,0.629l0.34,-2.205l1.532,-1.421l0.676,-1.138l1.41,-0.491l0.044,-0.804l1.232,0.335l0.049,-0.722l1.233,-0.412l1.355,-0.387l2.071,1.318l1.556,1.705l1.755,0.02l1.783,0.271l-0.594,-1.582l1.343,-2.303l1.264,-0.749l-0.437,-0.715l1.218,-1.632l1.698,-1.006l1.435,0.339l2.355,-0.537l-0.051,-1.455l-2.054,-0.936l1.493,-0.413l1.857,0.704l1.489,1.167l2.361,0.729l0.801,-0.288l1.738,0.875l1.638,-0.815l1.054,0.248l0.656,-0.547l1.287,1.41l-0.747,1.528l-1.064,1.155l-0.964,0.096l0.325,1.146l-0.824,1.435l-0.996,1.414l0.201,0.814l2.229,1.596l2.16,0.928l1.443,0.999l2.027,1.722l0.79,-0.003l1.468,0.746l0.426,0.901l2.677,0.992l1.852,-0.999l0.549,-1.566l0.568,-1.289l0.349,-1.59l0.853,-2.3l-0.39,-1.394l0.202,-0.837l-0.324,-1.643l0.367,-2.157l0.538,-0.581l-0.437,-0.953l0.678,-1.511l0.532,-1.563l0.07,-0.81l1.042,-1.063l0.791,1.388l0.194,1.783l0.699,0.344l0.119,1.197l1.02,1.452l0.21,1.62L877.779,502.097z" />
    <path id="BR" title="Brazil" class="land" d="M313.681,551.79L317.421,547.418L320.586,544.34L322.469,543.058L324.83,541.33L324.887,538.84L323.48,537.052L322.092,537.645L322.642,535.862L323.022,534.045L323.023,532.363L322.015,531.81L320.963,532.303L319.917,532.167L319.59,530.995L319.329,528.217L318.804,527.315L316.91,526.5L315.766,527.09L312.806,526.512L312.992,522.447L312.163,520.793L313.04,520.18L312.77,518.493L313.538,517.2L314.036,514.884L313.374,513.063L311.842,512.244L311.542,511.093L311.953,509.414L306.578,509.294L305.5,505.924L306.317,505.876L306.281,504.633L305.734,503.793L305.611,502.132L303.982,501.282L302.218,501.311L301.058,500.479L299.163,499.912L298.059,498.845L294.919,498.374L291.875,495.822L292.1,493.918L291.755,492.828L292.054,490.708L288.385,491.186L286.908,492.249L284.456,493.397L283.831,494.255L282.387,494.317L280.302,494.077L278.72,494.565L277.445,494.239L277.632,489.939L275.332,491.605L272.857,491.532L271.797,490.024L269.936,489.86L270.529,488.648L268.971,486.934L267.804,484.401L268.543,483.887L268.541,482.702L270.235,481.892L269.956,480.376L270.671,479.402L270.875,478.096L274.081,476.194L276.379,475.656L276.755,475.236L279.282,475.367L280.542,467.72L280.608,466.512L280.169,464.917L278.925,463.901L278.939,461.877L280.519,461.418L281.079,461.707L281.174,460.64L279.531,460.352L279.497,458.608L284.959,458.671L285.887,457.71L286.666,458.594L287.212,460.237L287.742,459.894L289.285,461.367L291.465,461.187L292.008,460.334L294.093,459.684L295.248,459.227L295.573,458.047L297.576,457.254L297.425,456.668L295.049,456.429L294.66,454.672L294.773,452.802L293.518,452.078L294.044,451.821L296.12,452.178L298.349,452.876L299.158,452.216L301.175,451.783L304.311,450.737L305.336,449.671L304.965,448.882L306.423,448.758L307.075,449.402L306.71,450.63L307.674,451.053L308.317,452.351L307.54,453.334L307.093,455.708L307.811,457.118L308.014,458.408L309.739,459.715L311.115,459.853L311.425,459.308L312.312,459.187L313.58,458.698L314.492,457.957L316.042,458.194L316.725,458.094L318.25,458.322L318.502,457.752L318.032,457.198L318.312,456.391L319.443,456.639L320.768,456.354L322.374,456.945L323.598,457.52L324.466,456.764L325.093,456.88L325.476,457.665L326.818,457.466L327.893,456.407L328.753,454.354L330.412,451.799L331.367,451.667L332.061,453.211L333.633,458.088L335.133,458.548L335.208,460.471L333.1,462.764L333.972,463.604L338.928,464.041L339.029,466.833L341.159,465.005L344.687,466.006L349.344,467.708L350.712,469.34L350.253,470.883L353.513,470.024L358.97,471.499L363.159,471.39L367.304,473.699L370.884,476.828L373.044,477.634L375.442,477.747L376.458,478.629L377.41,482.195L377.875,483.894L376.759,488.546L375.332,490.389L371.38,494.329L369.594,497.544L367.518,500.019L366.817,500.075L366.034,502.183L366.233,507.581L365.451,512.059L365.153,513.986L364.267,515.143L363.77,519.082L360.927,522.96L360.45,526.053L358.181,527.357L357.524,529.168L354.478,529.161L350.067,530.326L348.092,531.679L344.952,532.57L341.652,535.01L339.279,538.071L338.871,540.393L339.337,542.12L338.813,545.302L338.177,546.85L336.217,548.604L333.106,554.28L330.641,556.873L328.734,558.412L327.456,561.566L325.601,563.48L324.825,561.585L326.061,560.007L324.439,557.759L322.24,555.944L319.354,553.855L318.313,553.95L315.5,551.446z" />
    <path id="CA" title="Canada" class="land" d="M198.925,96.233l-0.222,-5.902l3.63,0.579l1.634,0.955l3.351,4.925l-0.76,4.97l-4.148,2.771l-2.284,-3.123L198.925,96.233zM212.14,108.876l0.334,-1.49l-1.968,-2.448l-5.646,-0.194l0.748,3.676l5.254,0.827L212.14,108.876zM248.488,155.832l3.085,5.103l0.812,0.574l3.069,-1.275l3.021,0.201l2.98,0.276l-0.248,-2.643l-4.835,-5.381l-6.417,-1.077l-1.349,0.666L248.488,155.832zM183.063,93.132l-2.708,4.188l6.242,0.516l4.615,4.438l4.579,1.498l-1.092,-5.68l-2.145,-6.726l-7.582,-5.353l-5.504,-2.044l0.204,5.687L183.063,93.132zM208.96,82.895l5.127,-0.116l-2.216,4.002l-0.043,5.297l3.013,5.756l5.811,1.766l4.96,-0.99l5.181,-10.729l3.85,-4.447l-3.38,-4.97l-2.215,-10.648l-4.599,-3.188l-4.718,-3.682l-3.581,-9.561l-6.521,0.937l1.225,4.149l-2.874,1.246l-1.943,5.322l-1.944,7.458l1.776,7.261L208.96,82.895zM145.21,136.272l3.92,1.953l12.667,-1.298l-5.824,4.771l0.357,3.431l4.264,-0.236l7.074,-4.58l9.495,-1.673l1.706,-5.218l-0.493,-5.569l-2.938,-0.502l-2.497,1.929l-1.099,-4.133l-0.945,-5.699l-2.895,-1.415l-2.569,4.411l4.01,11.049l-4.898,-0.851l-4.981,-6.788l-7.891,-3.998l-2.639,3.321L145.21,136.272zM167.773,94.206l-3.646,-2.897l-1.504,-0.659l-2.876,4.284l-0.045,2.002l4.656,0.014L167.773,94.206zM166.305,106.564l0.932,-3.985l-3.954,-2.125l-4.094,1.385l-2.271,4.261l4.159,4.207L166.305,106.564zM195.404,139.803l4.623,-1.106l1.277,-8.252l-0.087,-5.945l-2.144,-5.56l-0.216,1.596l-3.943,-0.699l-4.223,4.087l-3.017,-0.37l0.178,8.924l4.596,-0.868l-0.058,6.465L195.404,139.803zM192.118,185.406l-5.06,-3.927l-4.709,-4.208l-0.869,-6.18l-1.76,-8.925l-3.141,-3.839l-2.787,-1.547l-2.467,1.417l1.992,9.586l-1.409,3.731l-2.294,-8.979l-2.562,-3.105l-3.168,4.814l-3.899,-4.76l-6.239,2.868l1.399,-4.463l-2.865,-1.875l-7.507,5.838l-1.952,3.711l-2.354,6.771l4.896,2.317l4.325,-0.122l-6.503,3.461l1.479,3.129l3.976,0.169l5.991,-0.669l5.422,1.959l-3.66,1.445l-3.953,-0.372l-4.328,1.409l-1.865,0.874l3.455,6.354l2.489,-0.883l3.828,2.145l1.519,3.651l4.988,-0.725l7.105,-1.157l5.264,-2.646l3.26,-0.479l4.823,2.115l5.074,1.219l0.945,-2.859l-1.789,-3.049l4.604,-0.645L192.118,185.406zM199.863,184.425l-1.96,3.539l-2.468,2.486l3.829,3.541l2.284,-0.854l3.779,2.358l1.743,-2.732l-1.709,-3.03l-0.841,-1.526l-1.682,-1.458L199.863,184.425zM182.25,154.982l-2.131,-2.175l-3.757,0.397l-0.953,1.384l4.374,6.752L182.25,154.982zM210.937,168.154l3.008,-6.927l3.343,-1.848l4.189,-8.743l-5.356,-2.47l-5.842,-0.357l-2.782,2.77l-1.465,4.231l-0.043,4.817l1.75,8.188L210.937,168.154zM228.092,145.149l5.756,-0.185l8.043,-1.614l3.589,1.275l4.181,-2.26l1.749,-2.84l-0.626,-4.519l-3.003,-4.229l-4.556,-0.801l-5.709,0.969l-4.457,2.441l-4.091,-0.939l-3.782,-0.495l-1.781,-2.702l-3.217,-2.614l0.639,-4.433l-2.42,-3.982l-5.52,0.027l-3.113,-3.988l-5.779,-0.799l-1.055,5.096l3.25,3.745l5.8,1.454l2.815,5.095l0.341,5.602l0.97,5.99l7.452,3.417L228.092,145.149zM139.073,126.88l5.212,-5.053l2.62,-0.587l2.16,-4.228l0.385,-9.769l-3.846,1.914l-4.3,-0.18l-5.758,8.189l-4.759,8.977l3.799,2.51L139.073,126.88zM211.251,143.053l1.525,-4.14l-1.023,-3.458l-2.448,-3.918l-4.031,3.018l-1.493,4.924l3.399,2.787L211.251,143.053zM202.943,154.49l-0.729,-2.881l-5.002,1.264l-3.344,-2.107l-3.318,4.804l3.089,6.282l-5.725,-1.174l-0.056,3.011l6.968,7.046l1.94,3.38l2.701,0.731l4.598,-3.413l0.504,-8.211l-4.244,-4.074L202.943,154.49zM128.949,308.228l-1.157,-2.344l-2.799,-1.769l-1.386,-2.053l-0.954,-1.505l-2.635,-0.464l-1.721,-0.667l-2.943,-0.962l-0.242,1.021l1.08,2.38l2.886,0.781l0.505,1.231l2.509,1.502l0.841,1.513l4.604,1.92L128.949,308.228zM250.655,230.599l-2.002,-2.109l-2.063,0.498l-0.249,-3.062l-3.212,-2.035l-3.07,-2.267l-1.63,-1.753l-1.435,1.034l-0.521,-2.963l-2.026,-0.555l-0.956,6.134l-0.358,5.107l-2.438,3.136l3.8,-0.604l0.963,3.65l3.99,-3.225l2.78,-3.379l1.575,2.863l4.363,1.511L250.655,230.599zM130.121,178.055l7.38,-4.179v-3.874l3.477,-6.407l6.875,-6.689l3.525,-2.467l-3.01,-4.199l-2.723,-2.953l-7.162,-0.572l-4.004,-2.156l-9.477,1.625l2.742,6.225l-2.432,6.431l-1.942,6.866l-1.203,3.858l6.474,4.694L130.121,178.055zM264.358,205.358l0.316,-1.009l-0.031,-3.175l-2.189,-2.084l-2.57,1.047l-1.191,4.167l0.7,3.559l3.143,-0.361L264.358,205.358zM288.177,212.904l4.408,6.601l3.45,2.855l4.921,-7.87l0.873,-4.933l-4.41,-0.474l-4.03,-6.696l-4.451,-1.64l-6.604,-4.968l5.148,-3.634l-2.652,-7.542l-2.442,-3.354l-6.769,-3.352l-2.922,-5.549l-5.207,1.991l-0.363,-3.863l-3.862,-4.322l-6.221,-4.714l-2.652,3.714l-5.547,2.662l0.417,-6.064l-4.81,-10.052l-7.106,4.063l-2.591,7.701l-2.209,-5.923l2.063,-6.371l-7.24,2.651l-2.883,3.991l-2.155,8.421l0.889,9.051l3.983,0.038l-2.932,3.924l2.332,2.961l4.547,1.255l5.931,2.417l10.204,1.818l5.083,-1.044l1.501,-2.42l2.211,2.788l2.471,0.462l2.968,4.965l-1.796,1.98l5.68,2.626l4.295,3.678l1.081,2.55l0.771,3.239l-3.627,6.925l-0.979,3.443l0.937,2.423l-5.772,0.859l-5.269,0.119l-1.847,4.869l2.372,2.226l8.107,-1.031l-0.045,-1.889l4.083,3.148l4.183,3.276l-0.979,1.773l3.398,3.021l6.017,3.535l7.604,2.391l-0.456,-2.089l-2.92,-3.672l-3.963,-5.373l7.033,4.997l3.536,1.66l0.966,-4.438l-1.825,-6.298l-1.155,-1.729l-3.806,-3.035l-2.949,-3.911l0.354,-3.942L288.177,212.904zM222.346,51.338l2.336,7.293l4.957,5.88l9.811,-1.088l6.313,1.968l-4.375,6.053l-2.214,-1.776l-7.664,-0.712l1.19,8.314l3.96,6.036l-0.795,5.201l-4.972,3.462l-2.271,5.471l4.548,2.646l3.823,8.549l-7.497,-5.703l-1.71,0.941l1.381,9.377l-5.184,2.833l0.352,5.851l5.301,0.626l4.173,1.438l8.236,-1.845l7.327,3.269l7.492,-7.191l-0.061,-3.019l-4.791,0.482l-0.392,-2.841l3.917,-3.829l1.33,-5.151l4.332,-3.829l2.664,-4.762l-2.319,-7.103l1.938,-2.649l-3.865,-1.887l8.489,-1.628l1.787,-3.147l5.784,-2.604l4.795,-13.473l4.569,-4.943l6.616,-11.124l-6.104,0.098l2.535,-4.303l6.784,-3.993l6.841,-8.903l0.123,-5.731l-5.131,-6.042l-6.021,-2.93l-7.494,-1.819l-6.072,-1.489l-6.073,-1.503l-8.095,3.977l-1.49,-2.527l-8.57,0.976l-5.028,2.571l-3.701,3.65L242.028,30.5L239,24.517l-3.477,-1.142l-4.122,7.97l-5.501,3.348l-3.274,0.664l-4.169,3.837l0.614,6.646L222.346,51.338zM296.747,316.344l-0.982,-1.984l-1.059,1.262l0.701,1.361l3.556,1.713l1.039,-0.262l1.379,-1.656l-2.6,0.111L296.747,316.344zM239.747,238.477l0.614,1.63l1.979,0.138l3.282,-3.337l0.06,-1.188l-3.851,-0.059L239.747,238.477zM301.875,304.917l-2.867,-1.799l-3.687,-1.087l-0.97,0.365l2.607,2.039l3.634,1.343l1.365,-0.076L301.875,304.917zM326.765,309.712l-0.357,-2.235l-1.962,0.723l0.868,-3.113l-2.796,-1.321l-1.293,1.047l-2.488,-1.179l0.984,-1.509l-1.883,-0.933l-1.83,1.469l1.855,-3.825l1.497,-2.8l0.542,-1.217l-1.301,-0.197l-2.433,1.547l-1.738,2.529l-2.897,6.917l-2.354,2.558l1.22,1.144l-1.747,1.473l0.43,1.231l5.442,0.126l3.013,-0.248l2.69,1.005l-1.98,1.932l1.673,0.142l3.253,-3.576l0.781,0.528l-0.608,3.367l1.843,0.77l1.269,-0.151l1.18,-3.614L326.765,309.712zM305.569,314.475l-2.811,4.56l-4.633,0.581l-3.642,-2.009l-0.915,-3.07l-0.889,-4.462l2.648,-2.829l-2.482,-2.089l-4.195,0.426l-5.881,3.53l-4.501,5.452l-2.381,0.672l3.227,-3.804l4.044,-5.574l3.575,-1.899l2.348,-3.112l2.904,-0.303l4.208,0.031l5.997,0.919l4.74,-0.708l3.528,-3.624l4.621,-1.587l2.012,-1.58l2.035,-1.706l-0.205,-5.188l-1.126,-1.772l-2.184,-0.628l-1.111,-4.047l-1.8,-1.548l-4.471,-1.264l-2.521,-2.822l-3.729,-2.826l1.127,-3.197l-3.101,-6.26l-3.651,-6.893l-2.184,-4.983l-1.855,2.611l-2.682,6.053l-4.06,2.973l-2.032,-3.155l-2.561,-0.847l-0.932,-6.99l0.084,-4.797l-5,-0.438l-0.851,-2.266l-3.453,-3.436l-2.611,-2.039l-2.322,1.583l-2.883,-0.585l-4.807,-1.646l-1.952,1.397l0.937,9.177l1.222,5.116l-3.309,5.751l3.406,4.022l1.904,4.44l0.229,3.422l-1.554,3.504l-3.177,3.461l-4.489,2.281l1.978,2.529l1.464,7.402l-1.517,4.676l-2.159,1.458l-4.172,-4.283l-2.031,-5.168l-0.872,-4.759l0.458,-4.194l-3.05,-0.474l-4.63,-0.283l-2.971,-2.082l-3.513,-1.373l-2.006,-2.379l-2.803,-1.935l-5.21,-2.229l-3.923,1.02l-1.311,-3.947l-1.263,-4.99l-4.12,-0.902l0.155,-6.411l1.087,-4.483l3.041,-6.6l3.431,-4.902l3.262,-0.769l0.186,-4.048l2.213,-2.682l4.014,-0.424l3.252,-4.392l0.818,-2.897l2.703,-5.725l0.836,-3.5l2.899,2.107l3.899,-1.076l5.49,-4.964l0.357,-3.539l-1.977,-3.98l2.086,-4.057l-0.169,-3.865l-3.763,-3.953l-4.145,-1.19l-3.985,-0.624l-0.153,8.714l-2.045,6.555l-2.928,5.304l-2.712,-4.946l0.835,-5.606l-3.352,-5.018l-3.747,6.09l0.012,-7.991l-5.214,-1.626l2.488,-4.014l-3.809,-9.586L212,170.539l-3.698,-1.442l-3.315,6.428l-0.225,9.343l3.272,3.292l3.004,4.906l-1.268,7.708l-2.255,-0.202l-1.785,5.884l0.017,-7.004l-4.345,-2.583l-2.493,1.335l0.324,4.672l-4.09,-0.178l-4.353,1.173l-4.954,-3.353l-3.131,0.598l-2.818,-4.114l-2.263,-1.84l-2.243,0.773l-3.413,0.355l-1.811,2.614l2.862,3.187l-3.05,3.725l-2.989,-4.423l-2.388,1.302l-7.568,0.873l-5.068,-1.589l3.945,-3.736l-3.782,-3.902l-2.747,0.5l-3.859,-1.323l-6.562,-2.891l-4.288,-3.373l-3.396,-0.469l-1.059,2.357l-3.445,1.311l-0.379,-6.15l-3.733,5.505l-4.741,-7.321l-1.938,-0.892l-0.626,3.905l-2.092,1.904l-1.926,-3.393l-4.589,2.048l-4.2,3.551l-4.165,-0.98l-3.396,2.495l-2.461,3.276l-2.924,-0.717l-4.414,-3.8l-5.23,-1.936l-0.019,27.648l-0.015,35.43l2.761,0.167l2.731,1.556l1.958,2.436l2.491,3.596l2.728,-3.054l2.815,-1.793l1.488,2.855l1.889,2.229l2.567,2.424l1.753,3.794l2.867,5.881l4.767,3.204l0.078,3.124l-1.559,2.355l0.059,2.484l3.392,3.449l0.492,3.761l3.587,1.958l-0.399,2.79l1.562,3.958l5.078,1.825l2.003,1.887l5.428,4.227l0.376,0.011h7.963h8.324h2.756h8.546h8.271h8.412l8.417,0l9.528,0l9.593,-0.003l5.803,0.003l0.008,-1.644l0.949,-0.021l0.498,2.345l0.872,0.718l1.958,0.26l2.863,0.672l2.72,1.303l2.271,-0.545l3.449,1.089l1.138,-1.659l1.591,-0.663l0.623,-1.032l0.632,-0.554l2.607,0.856l1.932,0.102l0.67,0.566l0.938,2.382l3.147,0.627l-0.495,1.182l1.109,1.212l-0.478,1.56l1.177,0.513l-0.587,1.372l0.752,0.125l0.527,-0.597l0.55,0.898l2.103,0.501l2.132,0.042l2.273,0.412l2.508,0.779l0.915,1.256l1.816,3.037l-0.903,1.299l-2.279,-0.54l-1.415,-2.441l0.355,2.486l-1.337,2.17l0.147,1.838l-0.231,1.074l-1.815,1.267l-1.318,2.091l-0.617,1.321l1.539,0.237l2.081,-1.201l1.225,-1.059l0.833,-0.173l1.542,0.382l0.746,-0.591l1.368,-0.481l2.443,-0.469v0.002l0,-0.002l-0.249,-1.15l-0.134,0.044l-0.856,0.198l-1.118,-0.363l0.839,-1.317l0.855,-0.457l1.979,-0.565l2.37,-0.528l1.244,0.734l0.782,-0.851l0.889,-0.54l0.596,0.286l0.032,0.061l2.87,-2.73l1.265,-0.726l4.26,-0.027l5.167,-0.003l0.281,-0.978l0.897,-0.2l1.191,-0.616l0.995,-1.82l0.855,-3.148l2.139,-3.097l0.932,1.083l1.88,-0.7l1.245,1.187l-0.002,5.525l1.833,2.251l3.116,-0.483l4.488,-0.13l-4.868,3.261l0.107,3.291l2.129,0.283l3.133,-2.793l2.781,-1.584l6.21,-2.351l3.469,-2.616l-1.811,-1.46L305.569,314.475zM251.905,243.372l1.098,-3.124l-0.713,-1.233l-1.148,-0.132l-1.082,1.804l-0.131,0.413l0.736,1.771L251.905,243.372zM109.249,279.8L109.249,279.8l1.559,-2.354L109.249,279.8z" />
    <path id="CN" title="China" class="land" d="M784.628,410.405l-2.423,1.412l-2.299,-0.91l-0.081,-2.535l1.382,-1.341l3.063,-0.831l1.612,0.071l0.627,1.131l-1.232,1.301L784.628,410.405zM833.186,302.885l4.88,1.379l3.321,3.035l1.135,3.945l4.261,0.005l2.431,-1.647l4.634,-1.239l-1.474,3.761l-1.089,1.512l-0.961,4.462l-1.886,3.888l-3.402,-0.703l-2.407,1.4l0.739,3.357l-0.404,4.553l-1.432,0.103l0.017,1.929l-1.811,-2.244l-1.114,2.13l-4.33,1.625l0.438,1.975l-2.424,-0.136l-1.331,-1.172l-1.927,2.644l-3.09,1.984l-2.283,2.347l-3.92,1.057l-2.064,1.689l-3.02,0.981l1.49,-1.668l-0.587,-1.411l2.221,-2.454l-1.481,-1.93l-2.444,1.302l-3.165,2.544l-1.728,2.34l-2.75,0.173l-1.431,1.676l1.479,2.409l2.294,0.582l0.095,1.583l2.218,1.025l3.143,-2.513l2.489,1.374l1.813,0.093l0.455,1.836l-3.97,0.974l-1.311,1.872l-2.727,1.728l-1.439,2.393l3.019,1.864l1.102,3.307l1.706,3.046l1.904,2.529l-0.046,2.426l-1.76,0.887l0.671,1.725l1.65,1l-0.431,2.609l-0.712,2.518l-1.567,0.284l-2.047,3.407l-2.271,4.086l-2.604,3.676l-3.855,2.818l-3.9,2.553l-3.159,0.347l-1.714,1.34l-0.97,-0.979l-1.586,1.498l-3.919,1.504l-2.967,0.459l-0.957,3.151l-1.554,0.174l-0.735,-2.162l0.664,-1.157l-3.762,-0.959l-1.325,0.488l-2.823,-0.778l-1.335,-1.222l0.443,-1.738l-2.563,-0.553l-1.352,-1.138l-2.39,1.615l-2.726,0.349l-2.236,-0.016l-1.505,0.737l-1.453,0.442l0.424,3.433l-1.495,-0.082l-0.252,-0.703l-0.085,-1.24l-2.057,0.874l-1.214,-0.552l-2.082,-1.128l0.816,-2.507l-1.775,-0.587l-0.669,-2.801l-2.96,0.506l0.337,-3.635l2.655,-2.58l0.113,-2.566l-0.083,-2.398l-1.224,-0.75l-0.937,-1.86l-1.641,0.235l-3.023,-0.474l0.947,-1.334l-1.314,-1.986l-1.999,1.346l-2.352,-0.785l-3.232,2.03l-2.552,2.355l-2.262,0.395l-1.228,-0.849l-1.48,-0.077l-2.004,-0.732l-1.515,0.803l-1.854,2.341l-0.235,-2.481l-1.71,0.665l-3.27,-0.309l-3.172,-0.725l-2.275,-1.393l-2.179,-0.627l-0.941,-1.533l-1.575,-0.459l-2.831,-2.094l-2.248,-0.993l-1.162,0.773l-3.896,-2.265l-2.755,-2.065l-0.786,-3.629l2.012,0.445l0.375,-0.092l0.541,-0.458l0.125,-0.417l-0.521,-0.625l-0.042,-1.167l-0.729,-0.063l-0.5,-0.417l-0.063,-0.729l0.438,-0.021l-0.354,-1.167l0.188,-0.208l1.083,0.063l1.813,-2.583l0.646,-2.333l-1.063,-0.875l-1.771,-0.542l-1.583,0.313l-2.336,1.187l-3.206,-1.041l-0.333,-0.979l-1.458,-0.604l-0.444,-1.427l-2.071,-1.627l-0.499,-1.007l-0.421,-2.012l0.098,-1.381l-1.703,-0.812l-0.921,0.359l-0.711,-3.324l0.798,-0.829l-0.387,-0.85l2.677,-1.726l1.938,-0.718l2.968,0.492l1.061,-2.354l3.597,-0.44l0.999,-1.478l4.419,-2.031l0.394,-0.853l-0.224,-2.165l1.924,-0.995l-2.524,-6.754l5.555,-1.582l1.436,-0.886l2.022,-7.262l5.563,1.353l1.56,-1.86l0.134,-4.186l2.329,-0.395l2.134,-2.831l1.098,-0.352l0.736,2.97l2.356,2.23l3.999,1.565l1.935,3.319l-1.079,4.728l1.009,1.729l3.332,0.678l3.776,0.552l3.388,2.448l1.732,0.433l1.277,3.568l1.646,2.269l3.091,-0.088l5.787,0.852l3.729,-0.528l2.768,0.565l4.148,2.291l3.393,-0.003l1.241,1.164l3.265,-2.014l4.529,-1.312l4.202,-0.144l3.276,-1.337l2.012,-2.051l1.963,-1.297l-0.454,-1.28l-0.896,-1.499l1.473,-2.538l1.577,0.358l2.882,0.8l2.794,-2.101l4.275,-1.546l2.055,-2.662l1.974,-1.156l4.072,-0.541l2.213,0.459l0.307,-1.453l-2.541,-2.887l-2.25,-1.333l-2.155,1.538l-2.766,-0.647l-1.587,0.528l-0.723,-1.706l1.981,-4.228l1.365,-3.247l3.365,1.632l3.952,-2.739l-0.026,-1.929l2.531,-4.725l1.56,-1.45l-0.035,-2.522l-1.538,-1.095l2.315,-2.313l3.484,-0.845l3.718,-0.127l4.196,1.394l2.462,1.711l1.733,4.611l1.051,1.937l0.977,2.731L833.186,302.885z" />
    <path id="CO" title="Colombia" class="land" d="M263.917,463.809L262.717,463.149L261.341,462.227L260.544,462.669L258.165,462.283L257.481,461.085L256.959,461.129L254.154,459.539L253.774,458.674L254.82,458.465L254.696,457.069L255.354,456.059L256.745,455.872L257.925,454.12L258.998,452.655L257.965,451.991L258.494,450.37L257.861,447.812L258.462,447.077L258.02,444.707L256.885,443.212L257.244,441.847L258.147,442.048L258.676,441.213L258.025,439.555L258.366,439.143L259.814,439.232L261.918,437.264L263.073,436.963L263.1,436.029L263.617,433.637L265.225,432.321L266.992,432.267L267.215,431.675L269.409,431.912L271.615,430.477L272.708,429.84L274.065,428.467L275.059,428.642L275.794,429.392L275.25,430.351L273.449,430.828L272.737,432.248L271.652,433.062L270.837,434.115L270.494,436.134L269.717,437.786L271.164,437.975L271.523,439.271L272.142,439.89L272.364,441.023L272.031,442.064L272.129,442.65L272.819,442.885L273.487,443.864L277.093,443.594L278.722,443.951L280.695,446.364L281.828,446.064L283.848,446.214L285.446,445.895L286.438,446.376L285.933,447.884L285.307,448.823L285.087,450.828L285.651,452.684L286.448,453.513L286.545,454.138L285.124,455.526L286.141,456.141L286.887,457.115L287.742,459.894L287.212,460.237L286.666,458.594L285.887,457.71L284.959,458.671L279.497,458.608L279.531,460.352L281.174,460.64L281.079,461.707L280.519,461.418L278.939,461.877L278.925,463.901L280.169,464.917L280.608,466.512L280.542,467.72L279.282,475.367L277.878,473.883L277.041,473.817L278.85,470.978L276.703,469.672L275.02,469.912L274.007,469.43L272.462,470.167L270.375,469.817L268.723,466.896L267.425,466.178L266.53,464.864L264.665,463.544z" />

    <path id="CZ" title="Czechia" class="land" d="M522.807,307.861L521.515,307.061L520.198,307.281L518.021,305.983L517.034,306.302L515.457,308.037L513.374,306.673L511.791,304.837L510.36,303.804L510.063,301.979L509.572,300.683L511.61,299.729L512.651,298.631L514.665,297.773L515.368,296.927L516.107,297.438L517.358,296.974L518.688,298.403L520.784,298.788L520.609,299.999L522.132,300.904L522.55,299.773L524.474,300.264L524.739,301.631L526.824,301.895L528.114,304.025L527.278,304.03L526.844,304.804L526.2,304.99L526.017,305.963L525.48,306.165L525.404,306.561L524.447,307L523.205,306.929z" />
    <path id="DE" title="Germany" class="land" d="M503.072,278.923L503.122,280.798L505.956,281.92L505.926,283.617L508.776,282.721L510.353,281.407L513.519,283.299L514.842,284.812L515.498,287.205L514.716,288.449L515.734,290.098L516.428,292.547L516.209,294.11L517.358,296.974L516.107,297.438L515.368,296.927L514.665,297.773L512.651,298.631L511.61,299.729L509.572,300.683L510.063,301.979L510.36,303.804L511.791,304.837L513.374,306.673L512.385,308.624L511.378,309.158L511.775,311.878L511.514,312.582L510.64,311.733L509.295,311.606L507.291,312.35L504.818,312.173L504.419,313.264L503,312.116L502.154,312.344L499.149,311.075L498.573,311.978L496.188,311.949L496.544,308.974L497.962,306.074L493.922,305.288L492.599,304.165L492.757,302.27L492.197,301.287L492.515,298.319L492.044,293.629L493.729,293.627L494.439,291.916L495.138,287.691L494.614,286.108L495.162,285.11L497.505,284.853L498.025,285.893L499.929,283.56L499.288,281.767L499.159,279.022L501.278,279.664z" />
   
  </g>
</svg>
```